# How to change position of uicollectionviewcell with animation?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uianimation

I'm designing a screen of friends list that have `animation` like this:

[image]

I started with `collectionview` but I don't understand how to change position of `cells`.

I take two `uicollectionviewcell` one for image, name and second for all details like the list.

I also managed to change for collection to list but for `animation` i don't know how to do it.

Here it's my **Code:**

```
//MARK: - Collection view setUp -
extension CollViewAnimate {

    fileprivate func setUpCollView() {

        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self

        self.register(UINib(nibName: "NameCollCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "NameCollCell")
        self.register(UINib(nibName: "DetailCollCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "DetailCollCell")
    }

    func reloadTblData() {

        self.isList = !self.isList
        self.reloadData()
    }
}

//MARK: - Collection view Deleagtes & DataSources -
extension CollViewAnimate: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.arrFriendList.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        if self.isList {

            if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DetailCollCell", for: indexPath) as? DetailCollCell {

                cell.setUserDetails(self.arrFriendList[indexPath.row])

                return cell
            }

        } else {

            if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "NameCollCell", for: indexPath) as? NameCollCell {

                cell.setUserDetails(self.arrFriendList[indexPath.row])

                return cell
            }
        }

        return UICollectionViewCell(frame: .zero)
    }
}

//MARK: - Collection view FlowLayout Deleagtes -
extension CollViewAnimate: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        if self.isList {
            return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.width), height: (collectionView.frame.width / 5))
        }

        return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.width / 3), height: (collectionView.frame.width / 2.5))
    }
}
```

Here I used separate collection view file, my all code for `collectionview` is returned here, and `.xib` file for `collectionviewcell`.

please guide me to achieve this task, also give your suggestion for a suitable `controller`.

**Thank you**

Comment: it seems you are using this https://github.com/Yalantis/DisplaySwitcher repo for your requirement right?

Comment: Sorry sir, but i'm not using this repo, i would like to achieve this by my own with regular `collectionview`. with out using any dependency.

Comment: you have to make first of two flow layout class and after on click grid change       // Only update item size here
            self.updateFlowLayout()
            self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
                self.collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(self.gridFlowLayout, animated: true)
            }, completion: { (finished) in
            }) you can try this.

Comment: @DrashtiJaviya will you give any perfect example for creating flow layout?